# How to change the background color of table row based on value in table cell?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am using Angular `*ngFor` directive to generate a dynamic table. Here is the structure below:

```
       <tr *ngFor = 'let element of ph'>
            <td>{{element.timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{element.ph}}</td>                   
       </tr>
```

The example image of the generated table is displayed below.
[image: Image Example]

I want to color entire table rows containing 20 < PH Value < 50. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: use ngStyle directive. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: I tried to use [ngClass]. but I have no idea to use it for a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `[ngClass]` and apply a class if the values are what you want them to be.

Here, use this:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>Reading Time</td>
    <td>PH</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let element of ph'
      [ngClass]="{'color': (element.ph > 20 && element.ph < 50)}">
      <td>{{element.timestamp}}</td>
      <td>{{element.ph}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, as suggested by [Yoel Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9963247/yoel-rodriguez), you could also use `[class.color]` to apply it dynamically:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>Reading Time</td>
    <td>PH</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let element of ph'
      [class.color]='element.ph > 20 && element.ph < 50'>
      <td>{{element.timestamp}}</td>
      <td>{{element.ph}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the `color` css class:

```
.color {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-row-color)

**PS:** I'm not suggesting the `[ngStyle]` approach as writing inline styles is not really a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ngClass]`, but [`[ngStyle]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) is more fit for small style changes:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{<property>: <value>}">
```

And for your particular case:

```
<tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (20<ph && ph<50) ? 'red' : 'white'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use NgClass directive on your ph column.
something like:

```
<td [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">{{element.ph}}</td>
```

In other words, use particular class with particular styles if your condition is true.

Hope it helps!